# iPad Mini Heap Size

Tags: heap-memory, heap-size, ipad-mini

Is there anyone who knows the heap size of an iPad Mini? I've searched about it and I didn't find any good information. What I want to know is the exact or approximation size of the heap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not documented and depends a great deal on the device. I have both generations of mini here, the first is basically an ipad2, suspect it has 512 ram, you'll get memory warnings at around 120mb, the new retina one is the 64 bit processor, so although it has twice the ram, many processes actually use twice the ram, so it comes out around the same percentage of the devices total ram (around 25% of the total ram and you start experiencing memory warnings..)